# Overwrite blob file when using back up to URL in SQL Server v12

Tags: sql, azure, azure-storage, database-backups

How can we overwrite an existing backup blob file when using Backup to URL approach in SQL Server v12?

We are already aware that this should not be done and each time new backup file should be created, however looking for the approach if at all it comes down to saving some cost and need of having only one blob file present in the storage container when you are running backup schedules daily.

We are also aware that this was easily possible when using backup to disk option i.e. with the help of WITH INIT but does not seem to work when using backup to URL approach

Here is the current TSQL command which we are using, however the INIT option does not seem to be overwriting the backup blob file

```
Use Master

BACKUP DATABASE [Database_Name]
TO  URL = N'https://storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/file_name.bak' 
WITH Credential = N'Storage_Creds', INIT
GO
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Bhushan,

Please try the following:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [DatabaseName]  
  TO URL = 'https://<mystorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<mycontainername>/DatabaseName.bak'   
 WITH CREDENTIAL = '<mycredentialname>'   
,COMPRESSION  
,STATS = 5;
```

GO

Additional Information:
[SQL Server Backup to URL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-to-url?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mike, which parameter out of these two would take care of replacing the existing file? did I miss something in the documentation link provided because I did not find anything about replacing existing backup file if Compression or Stats is used. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the option WITH FORMAT is what was needed to get this working and posting it as an answer just for reference for everyone looking for the solution. 
Example usage

```
Use Master
BACKUP DATABASE [Database_Name]
TO  URL = N'https://storage_name.blob.core.windows.net/container_name/file_name.bak' 
WITH Credential = N'Storage_Creds'
FORMAT
GO
```

Reference: [Azure SQL Database forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9960d016-afdd-496a-83db-a0de0f7ca042/overwrite-blob-file-when-using-back-up-to-url-in-sql-server-v12?forum=ssdsgetstarted#1fb8ece4-ef55-4575-86cf-90fee293a097)

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This will remove the existing backup and overwrite it:

```
BACKUP DATABASE [databaseName]
TO URL = N'https://<storageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/backupname.bak'
WITH CREDENTIAL = N'Storage_Creds, COMPRESSION, STATS = 5, FORMAT
```